# Android 8 USB device attached broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, usb

I have 2 broadcast receivers, one dealing with connection/disconnection, one with the user permission required. Code is as follows:

```
public class DeviceAttachReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "redacted.permission";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            //Device was attached, ask for permission
            UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager)context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
            UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            usbManager.requestPermission(device, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0));
        } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            //Disconnected
            UsbMonitorConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}

public class UsbPermissionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (MonitorAttachReceiver.ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            boolean granted = intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false);
            if (granted) {
                //Permission granted, connect the device
                UsbMonitorConnection.connect(context, device);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, the first receiver (the connection one) works perfectly, a dialog pops up for the user to allow access to the device, however the second one doesn't. Before Android 8, this worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show where you set your BroadcastReceiver? Is it in manifest or somewhere in activity? According to documentation `Apps that target Android 8.0 or higher can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts`

Comment: Oh, right... So I have to dynamically register in the activity? Will it be enough to target a lower API? I'm not actually using Android 8.0 features... BTW, how am I supposed to use USB devices if I can't listen for them connecting? It's a required feature. Am I supposed to just run a thread and poll? It's basically a serial device, I'm using UsbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(...).